# Modify values in df according to if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

| quest | user 1 | user 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | -1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | -1 | 0 |

I would now like to transform this df in order to make all 0 into a 1 and everything else (1, -1) into a 0.

The resulting df should look like this:

| quest | user 1 | user 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Please include a script that initializes the dataframe (and ideally tests against the result you want) so that we can have tested answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
out = df.set_index('quest').eq(0).astype(int).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
df[['user 1', 'user 2']] = df[['user 1', 'user 2']].eq(0).astype(int)
```